# Moto G 2nd generation won't show update when unrooted

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I live in Canada and I bought my Moto G (XT1040) secondhanded last year and then started using Wind. I waited patiently for the lollipop upgrade since it came out but I am still stuck with 4.4.4.
I tried rooting the phone and it did notify me that an update to lollipop is available but it would constantly fail to upgrade, so I unrooted the phone but it still says that I already have the newest version.
I even tried updating it with my computer using the Motorola software but it still says that I have the newest version. 
What are my options now? Do I root it and try to flash it? Could if be a bigger problem?